# Clang Errors when running make for OpenSSL (iOS, i386, x86_64)

Tags: ios, openssl, makefile

Trying to build OpenSSL with Clang for iOS and keep getting these errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "start"
implicit entry/start for main executable
     (maybe you meant: _start_hash, _BN_CTX_start , _dtls1_start_timer )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "start"
implicit entry/start for main executable
     (maybe you meant: _start_hash, _BN_CTX_start , _dtls1_start_timer )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Builds fine for armv7, armv7s, arm64

Using: https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone with modifications for clang

At first I thought it was clang, so reverted back to good old gcc... problem still occurring so must be something else I am doing.. D:

---

**Update 1:**

I was previously using `-miphoneos-version-min=5.1` in the CFLAGS.

When changing the minimum to `-miphoneos-version-min=6.0` seems to compile now... although doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay solution as found here: 
https://github.com/danoli3/OpenSSL-for-iPhone

The issue was using `-miphoneos-version-min=` for the simulator CFLAGS.

Changing this the following fixed the issue for the target for iOS 5.1

`-mios-simulator-version-min=`